# Creating an Aging report Query

Tags: sql-server

I need your help in coming up with a query that would give me a payment ageing report. the simple data please look like below :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | Customer Name | Total Invoice | Paid Invoice | Paid Date | Amount | Aging 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | David         |     $100      |     $0       |10/10/2018 |  $100  |  1    

| 2  | David         |     $100      |     $80      |15/10/2018 |  $20   |  5    

| 3  | David         |     $100      |     $100     |18/10/2018 |  $0    |  8    

| 4  | Jonh          |     $250      |     $0       |18/10/2018 |  $100  |  0    


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | Customer Name | Total Invoice | Paid Invoice | Paid Date | Amount | Aging 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | David         |     $100      |     $100     |18/10/2018 |  $0    |  8   

| 2  | Jonh          |     $250      |     $  0     |18/10/2018 |  $250  |  0
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Please show your existing query

Comment: Why `Jonh` `Paid Invoice` and `Amount` become `$250` ?

Comment: i don't existing my query.

Comment: you can create simple for me

Comment: oh sorry jonh Pain Invoice $0

Answer (score 0):

You need the last row per customer. One neat way to do this is with the `row_number` windows function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY aging DESC) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: I can't apply this with my query

Comment: @CheaThaily care to elaborate?

Comment: I send my script to you

Comment: @CheaThaily it's impossible to make out this unformatted text in the comment. Please edit your question and add the table's structure and some sample data in it, not the result of some query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(Aging) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY aging DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM   mytable
```